# How FB chooses which data to use in Send Dialog

Tags: facebook-php-sdk

Facebook has this Send dialog. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/send-dialog  and from screenshot it is obvious image and text can be shown from page/link you are sharing. I am doing just that but only title appears from my link (my website) how could I optimize website to help this Send dialog use image and text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add [open Graph](http://ogp.me/) meta tags in head tag of your page you want to share.

- **og:title** for title of page.
- **og:image** for Image that will be shown in preview.
- **og:description** for description text to be shown in preview.

Below is example

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Your title</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="Your Title" />
<meta property="og:description"  content="Blah blah blah" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.exmaple.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.example.com/image.jpg" />
</head>
```

Comment: Thanx, that makes sense. This is kind of dumb that I cant vote on your answer and I am the one asking the question.

Comment: It's fine! But you can mark it as answer so it can help others who are beginner in social media development and looking for same in future.